# Feature of quaternion Cos, Cot etc

Tags: trigonometry, quaternions

I am new to SE Mathematica, and search gives no answer; so here is my problem:

During the testing of my numerical library for quaternions with Mathematica (package Quaternions) I observed the following behavior:

```
<<Quaternions`
a = Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4] *)

b = N[ArcCos[a]]
(* Quaternion[1.390115947, -0.8918751006, -1.337812651, -1.783750201] *)

Cos[b]
(* Quaternion[1., -2., -3., -4.] *)
```

i.e. the vector part is negated. I can reproduce the result for `ArcCos`,
but my code gives `Cos[b] = [1, 2, 3, 4]` (also given by the [quaternion postfix calculator](http://tamivox.org/redbear/qtrn_calc/index.html)). This is **not** a rounding problem, and not limited to this specific quaternion. The same happened for e.g. `Cot[ArcCot[a]`, where as the following is as I would expect:

```
b = N[ArcSin[a]]
(* Quaternion[0.1806803802, 0.8918751006, 1.337812651, 1.783750201] *)

Sin[b]
(* Quaternion[1., 2., 3., 4.] *)
```

My first guess was that it is related to branch cuts, but the analog complex functions give the expected result `Cos[ArcCos[1 + 2*I]] = 1 + 2*I`.

> Question: What is the explanation for the negated vector part for some trigonometric quaternion functions like $\cos$, $\cot$, etc.?

Comment: So what does N@ArcCos@Quaternion[1,-2,-3,-4] yield?

Comment: @lllamnyp: `Quaternion[1.390115947,-0.8918751006,-1.337812651,-1.783750201]` i.e. the same as `ArcCos[a]`.

Comment: So then it's clear that arccos prefers that particular branch

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: May be, but this breaks the relation $\arccos(z) + \arccos(-z)=\pi$. Meanwhile I found a difference in the source code: In Quaternions.m the back-transform from the corresponding complex function is`extfunc[func_, a_, b_] :=  Re[b] + AbsIJK[b]*AdjustedSignIJK[a]` where as my function uses an equivalent to `extfunc[func_, a_, b_] := Re[b] + AbsIJK[b]*Sign[a]`.  But changing the m source makes things worse.

Comment: I think something is wrong with `AbsIJK`. I believe the definition `AbsIJK[a_?NumericQ] := Im[a]` should be `AbsIJK[a_?NumericQ] := Abs[Im[a]]`, given that's what the other definition of `AbsIJK` does. I can file an internal report for this.

Comment: @ChipHurst: This looks a bit better, it causes `Cos[ArcCos[a]=a`, but it still breaks $\arccos(a)+\arccos(-a)=\pi.$

Comment: Does that identity hold over the quaternions?

Comment: @ChipHurst: Honestly I do not know, but it is valid for complex numbers and
Mathematica returns `FullSimplify[ArcCos[z] + ArcCos[-z]] = Pi` but even with your change I get for the essentially complex quaternion `a=[1,2,0,0]` the value
`ArcCos[a] + ArcCos[-a]] = [3.141592653589793, 3.057141838961996, 0., 0.]`

Answer (score 3):

It does seem to be a matter of branch cut choice. If I use a different definition for quaternionic `ArcCos[]` (e.g. the definition [in Morais *et al.*'s book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=YnS8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA130)):

```
<<Quaternions`

qq = N[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]];

Sign[qq - Re[qq]] ** Log[qq + Exp[Log[qq ** qq - 1]/2]]
   Quaternion[-1.39012, 0.891875, 1.33781, 1.78375]
```

compared with

```
ArcCos[qq]
   Quaternion[1.39012, -0.891875, -1.33781, -1.78375]
```

the former yields `qq` when `Cos[]` is applied to it, while the latter has the behavior shown in the OP.

We have here the amusing conclusion that in general $\cos q\ne\cos(-q)$ for quaternionic $q$.